# Plowmod installing failed macOS

Tags: macos, github, terminal

i'm trying to install Plowshare on my mac, and it's installed successfully
i used this GitHub link : https://github.com/mcrapet/plowshare

There is one problem with Plowdown ( it's part of Plowshare ) not installed!

Here the problem when i trying to install it via Terminal :

```
4832:~ MyMac$ plowmod --install
/usr/local/Cellar/plowshare/2.1.6/share/plowshare/core.sh: line 3758:         /usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/bin/gsed: No such file or directory
plowmod: no action specified!
plowmod: try `plowmod --help' for more information.


by the way,
cURL = installed + linked
Brew = installed + linked
gnu-sed = installed + linked
Bash = installed + linked
spidermonkey = installed + linked
recode = installed + linked
```

i don't know what is the problem, what shall i do!

Comment: Did you try `plowmod --help`? Also `man plowmod`.

Comment: You are amazing , really thank you .. " man plowmod " working finally :)